# Questions on constructing WML factor (Fama French)

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, finance-mathematics, statistical-finance

https://mba.tuck.dartmouth.edu/pages/faculty/ken.french/data_library.html

We can see that the Winner and Loser portfolios are determined by the cumulative return from t-12 to t-2.

To construct the WML factor here, size(market cap) must also be considered.
What date's market capitalization should be considered?

Since the WML factor is rebalanced every month, should I determine the 'Small' and 'Big' portfolios monthly based on marketcaps of companies at t-1?

Or should I sort it out once a year, just considering June's size, like when I make SMB factor?